# Shaded region between the area and a circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a square whose side is 6 inscribed in a circle and make the program display the shaded region between the square and the circle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple option; the value for `\side` controls half the side of the square:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\side{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=yellow!40] (0,0) circle (\side*1.4142);
\draw[fill=white] (-\side,-\side) rectangle (\side,\side);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option using the intersections library; this time the value for `\radius` controls the radius of the circle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\def\radius{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[name path=circle,fill=yellow!40] (0,0) circle (\radius);
\path[name path=line1] (-\radius,-\radius) -- (\radius,\radius);
\path[name path=line2] (-\radius,\radius) -- (\radius,-\radius);
\filldraw[draw=black,fill=white,
  name intersections={of=circle and line1,by={a,b}},
  name intersections={of=circle and line2,by={c,d}}] 
  (a) -- (c) -- (b) -- (d) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks; I want to make it small. Any idea?

Comment: @user10 sure: you can use a scaling factor: `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]...\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @user10 in my updated answer you find another option: you can simply change the value of `\radius` (initially set to 3).

Comment: how to use grey instead of yellow?

Comment: @user10 in my code, instead of `fill=yellow!40`, you can use `fill=gray!40` (which means 40% gray and 60% white) or any other shade of the desired color.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution using a `nonzero rule` fill. The parameters are:

- the `center` coordinate,
- the `\radius` distance,
- the `\angle` of square into the circle.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % parameters
  \coordinate (center) at (2,3);
  \def\radius{3cm}
  \def\angle{15}
  %
  \path[fill=lime,draw=black,thick]
  (center) circle (\radius)
  +(\angle:\radius) --
  +(\angle-90:\radius) --
  +(\angle-180:\radius) --
  +(\angle-270:\radius) --
  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And just for fun (credits to Qrrbrbirlbel):

[image: animated example]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \angle in {0,1,...,89}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (center) at (2,3);
    \def\radius{3cm}
    \fill[white] (center) +(-\radius,-\radius) rectangle +(\radius,\radius);
    \path[fill=lime,draw=black,thick]
    (center) circle (\radius) +(\angle:\radius) -- +(\angle-90:\radius)
    --  +(\angle-180:\radius) --  +(\angle-270:\radius) --  cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Just for fun.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsi0f.gif)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. I add this picture to my answer...

Comment: This is nice to see.. give the commands for this rotations..@PaulGaborit

Comment: @David Done....

Answer (score 5):

Some complements :

With the code of Paul, you can use `even odd rule` if you draw the square with anticlockwise

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % parameters
  \coordinate (center) at (2,3);
  \def\radius{3cm}
  \def\angle{15}
  %
  \path[fill=lime,draw=black,thick,even odd rule]
  (center) circle (\radius)
  +(\angle:\radius) --
  +(\angle+90:\radius) --
  +(\angle+180:\radius) --
  +(\angle+270:\radius) --
  cycle;
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

If you want to fill the area between two circles, you have the next possibilites

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=lime,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (2cm) circle (1cm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=lime,even odd rule] (0,0) circle (2cm) (0:1) arc (0:360:1) ;
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=lime] (0,0) circle (2cm) (0:1) arc (0:-360:1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

About the construction

You can use Tikz with tkz-euclide. You give two points like you want with tikz or tkz-euclide with cartesian coordinates or polar coordinates. Then you define the square and you get the point C and you can define the circle with diameter A and C

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} 
\usetkzobj{all} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \tkzDefPoint(2,1){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,2){B} 
  \tkzDefSquare(A,B) \tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
  \tkzDrawCircle[diameter,fill=lime](A,C)
    \tkzDrawSquare[fill=white](A,B)   
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Save the earth by reducing the number of used keystrokes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\foreach \ang in {0,15,...,345}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=green]
    {
        \pscircle{3}
        \rotate{\ang}
        \psframe(3;-135)(3;45)
    }
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The rotation angle step is intentionally set to a greater value to reduce the number of frames which in turn to reduce the used bandwidth to view it on your browser.

Comment: Relevant answer is [here(click)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193635/19356).