# Crop jpeg into circular tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2cm]{\includegraphics{myimage.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I modify the above code so that the included image is adapted to the circle shape and cropped of the exceeding parts?

I want to specify a shape (a circle) and then include an image respecting the given dimension and cropped.

Comment: Related Questions: [LaTeX Photo With Rounded Corners](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61896/latex-photo-with-rounded-corners) and [How to set actual width for a rounded corners image using TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213387/how-to-set-actual-width-for-a-rounded-corners-image-using-tikz).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use `path picture` key.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[circle,draw,
           text=white,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{frog}
               };
           }]{I'm watching you!};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Image is writelatex's `frog.jpg`

Comment: ooh dat frog! `:)`

Comment: I see a `latex-memes` package incoming.

Comment: Perfect choice of example picture and text.

Comment: This approach requires me to put some text inside the circle to make it visible. How can I get the full size image without any text?

Comment: @nimcap set the `minimum width`, `minimum heigth` or `minimum size`  keys to enlarge the node without text

Answer (score 47):

Here is another frog solution which also uses `path picture` beneath. If you don't mind loading `tcolorbox` for this purpose, you can use its `fill overzoom image` option for TikZ. This option takes a picture file name as parameter (here `frog.jpg` again) and scales this image to fit into (or better: over) the shape:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % one picture
  \node[circle,draw,inner sep=2cm,fill overzoom image=frog] (A) {};

  % some more
  \foreach \w in {1,2,...,6}
  {
    \path (A) (\the\numexpr\w*60\relax:\the\numexpr 3+\w/2\relax cm)
      node[circle,draw,inner sep=\the\numexpr\w*2\relax mm,fill overzoom image=frog] (B) {};
    \draw[very thick,red,->] (A)--(B);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

As a bonus, here are some more frogs put into different shapes (zoomed automatically):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=1cm,delta angle=180]
\path[draw,thick,fill overzoom image=frog]
  (0,0) arc [start angle=-90] -- ++(-2,0) arc [start angle=90] -- cycle;
\path[draw,thick,fill overzoom image=frog]
  (3.5,2) arc [start angle=0] -- ++(0,-2) arc [start angle=180] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

And, finally, just one frog which fills a path consisting of two separate parts:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[radius=1cm,delta angle=180]
\path[draw,thick,fill overzoom image=frog]
  (0,4) arc [start angle=-90] -- ++(-2,0) arc [start angle=90] -- cycle
  (3.5,6) arc [start angle=0] -- ++(0,-2) arc [start angle=180] -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: The `tcolorbox` package is amazing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18):

Since I could not find writelatex's `frog.jpg`, I'm using the [`Masked tree frog head`](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Frog#mediaviewer/File:Masked_tree_frog_head.JPG) from [Charlesjsharp](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Charlesjsharp) on Wikimedia, which is [851x567 px big](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?dummy=on&imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F5%2F5d%2FMasked_tree_frog_head.JPG).

I like to use `clip`, since one can then clip the image with lots of different shapes. In this case I clip the image with a circle of half the radius of the shorter length of the image, centered onto the middle of the image.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}  
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\imsize}{\linewidth}
\newlength\imagewidth
\newlength\imagescale

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\imsize}{0.618\linewidth}
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagewidth}{\textwidth}%
\pgfmathsetlength{\imagescale}{\imagewidth/851}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\imagescale,y=-\imagescale]
    \clip (851/2, 567/2) circle (567/2);
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\imagewidth]{Masked_tree_frog_head}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to enable anti-aliasing on this solution?

Comment: @Unapiedra: Tha anti-aliasing is most probably an artefact from the conversion from `pdf` to (tiny) `jpg`. The original file is cropped by a neat circle, as you can see in [this screenshot](http://cl.ly/WnSd) showing the zoomed in document.

Comment: You have a lot of seemingly magic numbers. I'd like to see this with more documentation or an explanation of those numbers.

Comment: @jvriesem The numbers are not magic at all. [The image I used is 851x567 px big](http://regex.info/exif.cgi?dummy=on&imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2F5%2F5d%2FMasked_tree_frog_head.JPG). I'm centering the circle with a radius of half of the smaller length on the middle of the image (851/2 and 567/2), The `\imsize` of 0.618 is 1/phi, from the [Golden ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), which would not be necessary for *this* example where only the image is shown and there's no text to relate the image width to.

Answer (score 11):

A bit enhanced circular clipper with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multido}
\newsavebox\IBox
%\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=3]{example-grid-100x100pt}}
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{golum}}

\def\HColumns{10} %half columns
\def\HRows{10} %half rows

\psset
{
    xunit=0.5\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\HColumns,
    yunit=0.5\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\HRows,
    runit=\psxunit,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-\HColumns,-\HRows)(\HColumns,\HRows)
    \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=12pt](-\HColumns,-\HRows)(\HColumns,\HRows)
    \psclip
    {
        \pscustom[linestyle=none,linewidth=0]
        {
            \code{ /clip /eoclip load def }
            \multido{\n=2+2}{5}{\pscircle(0,0){\n}}
        }
    }
    \rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \endpsclip
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the small circles are not drawn on the top but they clip the image with even-odd rule.

Comment: Do not know why, but I imagine that you were not gonna take the tender frog and sample image.

Comment: @Fran: I took a mutant of the frog. :-)