# includegraphics in tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I wanted to do this:

[Crop jpeg into circular tikz node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193555/crop-jpeg-into-circular-tikz-node)

but write with a variable width:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\def\mywidth{2cm}
\tikz\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1.2*\mywidth
           text=white,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=1.2\mywidth]{frog}
               };
           }]{I'm watching you!};
\end{document}
```

Why does this not work? The `includegraphics` command does not display the image in `1.2\mywidth` but some arbitrary size. The circle is the right size.

### Second examples

#### Code 1

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\def\firstwidth{1cm}
\def\secondwidth{2\firstwidth}

\tikz\node[circle,draw,minimum size=\firstwidth,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=\firstwidth]{blackbox.png}
               };
           }]{};
\end{document}
```

#### Result 1

[image]

#### Code 2

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\def\firstwidth{1cm}
\def\secondwidth{2\firstwidth}

\tikz\node[circle,draw,minimum size=\firstwidth,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=0.5\secondwidth]{blackbox.png}
               };
           }]{};
\end{document}
```

#### Result 2 (should be like Result 1)

[image]

Comment: maybe you need `\def` instead of `\dev`?

Comment: @percusse: Typo. Issue remains of course.

Comment: How about the missing `*` sign?

Comment: Can you make a sketch what you like to obtain? And where you like to place your frog on page?

Comment: @Zarko: It's supposed to look as in the link. Difference only in size.

Comment: @percusse: Within the node text I should be in standard LaTeX syntax. Of course I had tried anyway and failed.

Comment: I can reproduce image as it is given link with the following two changes: `minimum size=\mywidth` and `\includegraphics[width=4.4\mywidth]{...}`. For test I use `example-image` from `graphicx` package.

Comment: @Zarko: I added another example with images - maybe that clarifies the situation.

Comment: Instead to use `\def\mywidth{2cm}` try to use `\newlength\mywidth \setlength\mywidth{2cm}` and similarly at other lengths. This work fine at me.

Comment: @user49283, see my answer. Let me know, if it solve (at least a part of) your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem is how are defined lengths `\mywidth`, `\firstwidth` and `\secondwidth`. If insted of `\def\mywidth{2cm}` etc use definitions:

```
\newlength\mywidth\setlength\mywidth{2cm}

\newlength\firstwidth
\setlength\firstwidth{1cm}

\newlength\secondwidth
\setlength\secondwidth{2\firstwidth}
```

Your example will work as you expected (of course, if I correctly understand your problem):

[image]

Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\newlength\mywidth\setlength\mywidth{2cm}

\newlength\firstwidth
\setlength\firstwidth{1cm}

\newlength\secondwidth
\setlength\secondwidth{2\firstwidth}

\tikz\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1.2\mywidth,
           text=white,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=1.2\mywidth]{example-image-a}
               };
           }]{see};

\tikz\node[circle,draw,minimum size=\firstwidth,
           text=white,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=\firstwidth]{example-image-b}
               };
           }]{see};

\tikz\node[circle,draw,minimum size=\firstwidth,
           text=white,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=0.5\secondwidth]{example-image-c}
               };
           }]{see};
\end{document}
```