# Keep centered a cropped jpeg image into circular tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

This is a follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281231/180429).

Once I positioned the node that crops the image relative to another node, the cropped image is not centered any more inside the circle.

How to fix it?

I want the letter "A" of the `example-image-A` to be centered.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={draw=blue,line width=1pt},background rectangle/.style={fill=olive!25}, show background rectangle]

\node [text width=0.5\textwidth,font={\large\bfseries\sffamily},align=center] at (0,0) (A) {%
John Doe
};
\node[above= 1 ex of A,circle,draw,minimum size=0.3\textwidth,
           path picture={
               \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
                   \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a.png}
               };
           }] (B) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `anchor=center` to the node inside the `path picture`. It inherits the implicit `anchor=south` from the `above=…` key (as well as other options).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What's happening?

Your inner node (the one inside the `path picture`) inherits all options of its parent node (and also the `every node` style, of course). Importantly, it does inherit `anchor=south` that is implicitly set by `above=…`.

You need `anchor=center` at the path picture node to reset this.

### Alternative to `\node`

If you don't actually need all the bells and whistle of a node and just want to insert a picture (or text) in the path picture, you might better be off using the `\pgftext` macro.

---

Since the path picture's center of an otherwise empty node is always at its origin, we can actually leave the `at` part out in both cases.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={draw=blue, line width=1pt},
  background rectangle/.style={fill=olive!25},
  show background rectangle]
\node[
  text width=0.5\textwidth, font=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
  align=center] at (0,0) (A) {John Doe};
\node[above=1ex of A, circle, minimum size=0.3\textwidth, path picture={
    \node[anchor=center, draw=none, rectangle]
%        at (path picture bounding box.center)
      {\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}};}] (B) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={draw=blue, line width=1pt},
  background rectangle/.style={fill=olive!25},
  show background rectangle]
\node[
  text width=0.5\textwidth, font=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
  align=center] at (0,0) (A) {John Doe};
\node[above=1ex of A, circle, minimum size=0.3\textwidth, path picture={
    \pgftext[
%      at=\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{center}
    ]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}};}] (B) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Even better: The `tikzfill` package.

That said, there seems to be a [`tikzfill` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzfill) that already solves all your problems, maybe?

Here, I'm using the `fill overzoom image` that stretches a given image so that it fully covers the path picture.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fill.image}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={
    draw=blue,
    line width=1pt},
  background rectangle/.style={
    fill=olive!25},
  show background rectangle]

\node[
  text width=0.5\textwidth,
  font=\large\bfseries\sffamily,
  align=center] at (0,0) (A) {John Doe};

\node[above=1ex of A, circle, minimum size=0.3\textwidth,
  fill overzoom image={example-image-a.pdf}
  ] (B) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```