# Adding a Border to an Oval-Shaped Cropped Image

Tags: graphics, tikz-pic, border, crop, overpic

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \clip (0,0) ellipse (4.25cm and 5.5cm);
            \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-a}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the cropped image:

[image]

QUESTION: How may I add a gold border (of a specified thickness) around the oval-shaped cropped image? I am using `xelatex` to compile.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will draw the frame inside the node.

Notice that half the width of the line is lost in the clip.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \clip (0,0) ellipse (4.25cm and 5.5cm);
            \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-a}};
            \draw[line width=10pt, Gold] ellipse (4.25cm and 5.5cm); % added <<<<<<<<<<
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Answer (score 1):

To avoid clipping of the golden contour, the scope of the clipping path can be limited using the `scope` environment. This prevent parts of the clipped object from extending beyond the overlaid contour (caused by numerical imprecision of the PDF viewer / image conversion tool).

Also, the clipping path can be defined once and re-used elsewhere using `save path` and `use path` options:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{scope}
        \clip[save path=\myContour] (0,0) ellipse (4.25cm and 5.5cm);
          \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-a}};
      \end{scope}
      \draw[line width=5pt, Gold,use path=\myContour];
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the [`path picture`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#tikz/path:picture) is made for. With it you can put arbitrary TikZ stuff inside the path, the area that would be filled by the `fill` color, by a pattern or a shading.

I'm also using the low-level [`\pgftext`](https://tikz.dev/base-scopes#pgf.back/pgftext) here to avoid [the inner node to inherit any other options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664026/16595) from its parent path (for example, that node would also have a Gold drawn border, though we don't see that because it gets clipped).

In the previous link I also mention the [`tikzfill` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzfill) which gives a few predefined options for placing a picture inside a path.

### Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{228,168,73}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[Gold, ultra thick] (0,0) ellipse (4.25cm and 5.5cm) [path picture={
      \pgftext[at=\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{center}]
              {\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-a}}
      % \node at (path picture bounding box.center)
      %    {\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-a}};
    }];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```