# fill polygon with image / crop image by polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-shape

I would like to have an arbitrary polygon filled with an image (jpg, png, pdf, ...) for it to be included in a beamer frame.

I was thinking this may be possible using tikz, but I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Like so http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193555/crop-jpeg-into-circular-tikz-node ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Crop jpeg into circular tikz node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193555/crop-jpeg-into-circular-tikz-node) is valid for any kind of node (rectangle, circle or any already defined shape), but you can also define irregular polygons with a `clip` path:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{I'm watching you!}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-1,1)--++(-20:5cm)--++(75:4.5)--++(150:2cm)--++(200:3.5)--cycle; 
\node at (2,2) {\includegraphics[width=6cm]{frog}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great! this is what I was looking for. Could you help me with the specification of the polygon nodes? Let's say I want a polygon with the corner coordinates (x,y) = (0cm,0cm) (1cm,0cm) (2cm,1cm) (0cm,1cm), what is the \clip line going to look like? Thanks

Comment: @Bastian `\clip (0,0) --(1,0)-- (2,1)--(0,1)--cycle;`