# precisely position and crop images on beamer slide using polygonal contours

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to achieve slides like this:
[image: desired output]

So far I have learned [how to cut images using polygonal paths](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312670/fill-polygon-with-image-crop-image-by-polygon)
and [how to create frames without any margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3927/63717).

However I could not manage to combine the two in order to get the desired output.

My MWE is as follows, images can be retrieved [here](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464013778555-8e723c2f01f8) and [here](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463595373836-6e0b0a8ee322).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{frame}[plain,b]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \clip (0\paperwidth,0\paperheight)--(0.4\paperwidth,0\paperheight)--(0.6\paperwidth,1\paperheight)--(0\paperwidth,1\paperheight)--cycle; 
        \node[anchor=south west] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{photo-1463595373836-6e0b0a8ee322.jpeg}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `paperwidth` and `papweheight`, I've used `current page` anchors and `calc` tikzlibrary to define the clipping path.

Instead of `width` as scale factor for both images, I've used `height` because otherwise they were not tall enough to cover the slide.

Finally `inner sep=0pt` was fixed to avoid white margin around figures.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{frame}[plain,b]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (current page.south west)|- 
              ($(current page.north west)!0.6!(current page.north east)$) --
              ($(current page.south west)!0.4!(current page.south east)$) --
              cycle;
        \node [anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] at 
              (current page.south west)
              {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{photo-1463595373836-6e0b0a8ee322.jpg}};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
        \clip (current page.south east)|- 
              ($(current page.north west)!0.6!(current page.north east)$) --
              ($(current page.south west)!0.4!(current page.south east)$) --
              cycle;
        \node[anchor=south west, draw, inner sep=0pt] 
             at (current page.south west)
             {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{photo-1464013778555-8e723c2f01f8.jpg}};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

using `15.6 Generalized Filling: Using Arbitrary Pictures to Fill a Path`, I manage to do :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{frame}[plain,b,fragile]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[path image/.style={
      path picture={
        \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {
          \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{#1}
        };}}]
    \draw [path image=example-image-a] (0,0)--(0.4\paperwidth,0\paperheight)--(0.6\paperwidth,\paperheight)--(0\paperwidth,\paperheight)--cycle; 

    \draw [path image=example-image] (0.4\paperwidth,0\paperheight)--(\paperwidth,0\paperheight)--(\paperwidth,\paperheight)--(0.6\paperwidth,\paperheight)--cycle; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `fragile` as frame option.

Comment: this one is nicely concise, but I don't actually want the margin on the left

Comment: @Bastian Yes, but I don't understand why there is this margin.