# Round Crop an inserted image

Tags: graphics, crop

I wanted to obtain the same result as shown at [Crop an inserted image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image)

by having a round (rather than rectangular) crop or viewport.

Any idea of how to obtain this effect?

Thanks.

Comment: Combine it with tikz and its clip to path capabilities

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193555/134144 might he helpful.

Comment: great!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is command `\clipinoval` in OpTeX:

```
\clipinoval 3cm 3.5cm 6cm 7cm {\picw=6cm \inspic{myphoto.jpg}}
\end
```

Try to process this document by `optex document` when `myphoto.jpg` is in your current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to leandriis' example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \clip (0,0) circle (1);
  \node[inner sep=0pt]  at (0,0) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```