# crop image with complex custom shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, irregular-shape, crop-image

I want to crop an image on a complex shape. The shape will be applied to different images and used in a `{beamer}` presentation.

I took a example picture from [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:L%27automne_au_Qu%C3%A9bec_(8072544123).jpg) and clipped it by hand so that is looks like this:

[image]

The crop lines need to be adjusted to 90°/ 45° angles and corner points need to be calculated  using fractions of `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`.

I've seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193555/crop-jpeg-into-circular-tikz-node/193592#193592) that shows how to crop an image in general, but there the image is  cropped using *regular build-in shapes*. So my question here is:

Based on the solution of the other question: **How do I create an irregular custom shape**, that I can use to crop an image?

Comment: What will appear outside the cropped area? For example, within the "whitespace" at the top right? You could consider this to be a rectangular image with a white irregular shape overlaid on the image - easily doable with Ti*k*z... unless you want the background of the [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) theme to show through.

Comment: This might be useful: [How can I invert a 'clip' selection within TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12010/5764)

Comment: @Werner At least it shows how to create the custom shape. Unfortunately I have no clue how to replace the `circle` part in the clipping example I found first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that what you want? In fact, by adding an image through TikZ's node, name it, say `(A)`, scale it if needed, then on that image, from anchors (like `(A.120)`, `(A.north east)`, etc) you can `draw`, `fill`, `clip`, or put some `pic` with any shape you design.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Drawing on an image}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:L%27automne_au_Qu%C3%A9bec_(8072544123).jpg
\node[scale=1.2,inner sep=0] (A) {\includegraphics{autumn}};
\draw[white,fill=white] (A.110)
--++(-90:1)--++(-45:2)--++(0:2)--++(-45:1.5)
--++(-90:1.5)-|(A.north east)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here is a *clipping* using `pic`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Clipping on an image}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[house/.pic={
\fill[white] (-1,0)--(1,0)--(1,1.5)--(0,2)--(-1,1.5)--cycle;    
}]
%https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:L%27automne_au_Qu%C3%A9bec_(8072544123).jpg
\node[scale=1.2,inner sep=0] (A) {\includegraphics{autumn}};
\path ([shift={(-3,.5)}]A.center) pic[scale=.8]{house};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```